# Как решить вопрос неправильного масштабирования адаптивной вёрстки?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Делаю адаптивную вёрстку.
Прописываю метатэг

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Если сжимать окно браузера, то вёрстка ведет себя так, как нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я проверяю вёрстку в Google Chrome при имитации различных
устройств, то вёрстка отображается 1024px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно вылечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте определить девайс юзера и потом редиректить его на адаптивную версию сайта

Comment: Для чего это надо?

Comment: Виктор, вы же хотите сделать адаптивную верстку сайта?Если да, то вариант который у вас- проще, но менее надежен, а вариант, которой предложил я - сложнее и более громоздкий, но более надежен.   <br>P.S: определить девайс пользователя можно, определив, какой у пользователя браузер.<hr>Вот смотрите здесь :

Comment: У меня вёрстка адаптивная, зачем мне редиректить пользователя на другую версию? Я не делаю отдельно версию десктопную, а отдельно мобильную.